# How to return to view controller in main.storyboard from a xib without using navigation controller or navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am making an app with different view controllers. My home screen is in **main.storyboard**. Rest of the view controllers have their own **xib**, **.h** & **.m** files. I am trying this for navigation from home screen.

```
-(IBAction)btnSignUpTapped:(id)sender
{
    SignUpWithEmailViewController * login = [[SignUpWithEmailViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                   initWithRootViewController:login];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This code works fine for navigating to different viewcontroller (in this case `SignUpwithEmailViewController`). On `SignUpWithEmailViewController` I have a back button which is supposed to bring me back to home screen. This is what I got so far:

```
-(IBAction)btnBackTapped:(id)sender
{
    ViewController * homeScreen = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                   initWithRootViewController:homeScreen];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

But as result of this code, screen turns black and nothing happens. How do I solve this problem? For hiding the nav bar I am using

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Try using UIViewController *controller = [[classType alloc] initWithNibName:className bundle:nil] ?

Comment: So if i want to get the main storyboard view, i will do this?
UIViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:ViewController bundle:nil] ? and then present it? it says "Unexpected interface: ViewController". I don't have a xib named ViewController, to be sure.

Comment: If you want it from your Storyboard, you'll have to do this: UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MMSMenuViewController"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to insert you called viewController to NavigationController,
but if you wont to use modal flow - to close presentedViewController just call:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

**EDITED:**

may be it will be more helpful, it just example, put it to you main view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    c.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self presentViewController:c animated:YES completion:^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: It does work. Let me see if i can find some better solution. if not, i will mark it as the answer